# How to make a radio appear as the header? Also how do I get the radio to decide the next box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

I have been struggeling quite a while trying to figure out how to get the radio selected to show up in the header. Example: Let's say I click Baden-Wurttemberg, how can I get it to say Baden-Wurttemberg where it currently says province?

Also, in other to advance further, when you click Baden-Wurttemberg, it would be desirable to get the regions within that bundesland (province) to come up as the next option as you move on to the next box. Example: If you want to find Munich, you should be able to click on Bavaria and move on to the next box having Munich as an option.

I would appreciate it a lot if anyone could share their knowlegde!

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}



.menu-container {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0;
}
.menu {

    width:100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
.menu a, .menu a:link, .menu a:visited, .menu a:focus, span {
    color: #23255e;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover {
    color: #23255e;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11);
    box-shadow: -0px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.menu > li > a {
    padding:20px 140px;
    display: block;
}
.menu > li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
.menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #23255e;
}
/* Megadrop width dropdown */
 .menu > li > .megadrop {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    top:53px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #23255e;
    border-right: 1px solid #23255e;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23255e;
}
.menu > li:hover .megadrop {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.menu ul li:hover:after {
    color: #23255e;
}
.menu .col {
    width: 14.1%;
    float: left;
    color:white;
    margin: 0 0 0 ;
}
.menu .col ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu .col ul li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.menu .col h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    color: #23255e;
    background: white;
}
.menu .col ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #23255e;
}
.menu .col ul li a:hover {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > li > ul li ul, .menu li >ul li, .menu > li > .megadrop, .menu > li > ul, .menu > li {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-outs;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="euprop.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Province</a>

            <div class="megadrop">
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Independent Cities</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_1"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_1" />Berlin</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_2"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_2" />Bremen</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_3"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_3" />Hamburg</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Provinces</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_4"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_4" />Baden-Wurttemberg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_5"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_5" />Bavaria</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_6"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_6" />Hesse</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_7"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_7" />Mecklenburg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_8"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_8" />Lower Saxony</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_9"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_9" />North Rhine-Westphalia</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_10"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_10" />Rhineland-Palatinate</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_11"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_11" />Saarland</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_12"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_12" />Saxony</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_13"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_13" />Saxony-Anhalt</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_14"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_14" />Schleswig-Holstein</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_15"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_15" />Thuringia</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="active">Region</a>

            <div class="megadrop">
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Independent Cities</h3>

                     <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_16"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_16" />Baden-Baden</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_17"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_17" />Freiburg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_18"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_18" />Heidelberg</label>
                        </li>
      <li><label for="radio_19"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_19" />Heilbronn</label>
                        </li>
      <li><label for="radio_20"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_20" />Karlsruhe</label>
                        </li>
      <li><label for="radio_21"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_21" />Mannheim</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <div class="col">
                     <h3>Independent Cities</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_22"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_22" />Pforzheim</label>
                        </li>
      <li><label for="radio_23"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_23" />Stuttgart</label>
                        </li>
      <li><label for="radio_24"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_24" />Ulm</label>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Regions</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_4"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_4" />Freiburg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_5"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_5" />Karlsruhe</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_6"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_6" />Stuttgart</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_7"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_7" />Tubingen</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">District</a>

            <div class="megadrop">
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Independent Cities</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_1"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_1" />Berlin</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_2"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_2" />Bremen</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_3"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_3" />Hamburg</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Provinces</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_4"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_4" />Baden-Wurttemberg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_5"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_5" />Bavaria</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_6"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_6" />Hesse</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_7"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_7" />Mecklenburg</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_8"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_8" />Lower Saxony</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_9"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_9" />North Rhine-Westphalia</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="radio_10"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_10" />Rhineland-Palatinate</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_11"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_11" />Saarland</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_12"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_12" />Saxony</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_13"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_13" />Saxony-Anhalt</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_14"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_14" />Schleswig-Holstein</label>
                        </li>
                        <li><label for="radio_15"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_15" />Thuringia</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
          
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Municapality</a>

            <div class="megadrop">
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                     <h3>Title</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but i would say you may need to add a `"onclick="` to the input and a function that maybe uses a `.innerHTML` to push the value from the radio button into the heading, your heading will need an id also  like: `<h3 id="provincesAnswer">Provinces</h3>`

The function will need to take into account that all the radios are point at the heading, so you may need to go inline (i am sure someone else would have an easier way but as i said i am no expert).

So the radio may look like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_4" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Baden-Wurttemberg">Baden-Wurttemberg
```

So to simplify what i mean
here is the script:

```
<script>
function check(provincesValue) {
    document.getElementById("provincesAnswer").value=provincesValue;
}
</script>
```

And Your Heading:

```
<h3 type="text" id="provincesAnswer">Provinces</h3>
```

And A Few Radio buttons for example:

```
<li><label for="radio_4"><input type="radio" name="provincesValue" id="radio_4" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Baden-Wurttemberg" />Baden-Wurttemberg</label>
</li>
<li><label for="radio_5"><input type="radio" name="provincesValue" id="radio_5" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Bavaria" />Bavaria</label>
</li>
```

Hope this helps